# Tar backup keeps increasing in size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, tar

I've got a backup script that's supposed to backup the whole system, but it keeps increasing in size days after the backup. I've set to do one backup each day in crontab.

```
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`            
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz    
SRCDIR=/                    
DESDIR=/home/backup            
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME --exclude=/home/backup --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev  $SRCDIR
```

Is there some other directory that is constantly changing that i need to exclude aswell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By how much are they increasing? You could try extracting two tar packages to their own folders and run a differential program to show the changes, or write a simple bash script to mark new files and directories.

Comment: Over the weekend it increased by about 2gigs, I'm not very wellversed in bashscript, wouldnt know how to do that.

Comment: Jadi has a good answer. Finding the disk usage of each directory will point you to the increasing file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also exclude /var/log.

If you have some database on the system, it's ok that the size of the backup grows.

Comment: Thanks, it stopped growing now!

Answer (score 6):

the `du -hs` command can show you the disk space used in each directory. You can do a `cd /` and then `du -h --max-depth 1` to check each directories size. From there you can tell why the tar size is increasing.